# Easing on Animate Scroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, effect, easing

I'm trying to create an ease effect on my animate function in jQuery, but I'm having some trouble. Here's what I have so far:

```
function myCustomFunction(id){
    var divTag = $("div[name='"+ id +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: divTag.offset().top}, 800);
}
```

The ease I want to use is called "easeOutQuint". I tried to follow the example here (http://easings.net/#easeOutQuint) but wasn't able to apply the example to my function.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you were not able to apply the example? What error are you getting?

Comment: I tried adding it the way @user2039846 mentioned below, but it removed the scrolling function altogether for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, include first script from section *download* on this page:(http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

Then type jQuery animate line like this below:

```
function myCustomFunction(id){
var divTag = $("div[name='"+ id +"']");
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: divTag.offset().top}, 800, 'easeOutQuint');
}
```

Here you can see example...
http://jsfiddle.net/Gq367/

As you can see, you missed the easing parameter in jquery animate function.
Quick reminder: .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

I'm interested why you select div by name attribute?

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I thought the easing was built directly into jQuery. Once I downloaded that easing file, everything started working. Also, the reason I'm using the "div[name='"+ id +"']" is because I'm running the script after the completion of a vimeo video. So the whole code looks like this:

    function scrollToAnchor(id){
        var divTag = $("div[name='"+ id +"']");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: divTag.offset().top}, 2000, 'easeOutQuint');
    }

    function onFinish(id) {
        scrollToAnchor('story');
    }

Comment: If I set 4000 for a relatively small height it looks very good but since it's a long duration in order to have this nice effect, the form freezes for scrolling because the easing isn't over yet but the control has been reached.  I'm wondering if there's a solution for that.  Based on many tests, under 2000 the easing is barely perceivable.

Comment: You can always listen to scroll event and stop animation if someone started scrolling